# Copy video quality on FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, avi, video-codecs

I want to use FFmpeg to add a watermark but I want the video will have the same quality. How do I do that?

I tried to use `-vcodec copy -acodec copy` but was without watermark:

```
ffmpeg -y -i treino.mp4 -vf "movie=logo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" -vcodec copy -acodec copy video2.mp4
```

Comment: How to get the original encoding information automatically and preset for the new file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a filter, and filtering requires re-encoding, so you can't use `-vcodec copy` to [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the video. If you want the "same quality" then you'll need to use a lossless encoder:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex overlay -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- The resulting file may be huge: this is expected for lossless outputs.
- Your player or device may not be able to play the lossless file.
- If you want a "visually lossless" output, which is not technically lossless but appears to be nearly so, then use `-crf 18` instead of `-crf 0`.
- No need for the *movie* source filter. Just add your overlay image as in input like any other file as shown in my example.
- Since you're using PHP, I'll assume you're going to present the videos via progressive download. Add `-movflags +faststart` so it can begin playback before the file is completely downloaded.